# How does this implementation of the Python sum function work?

Tags: python

I have found an example online of how to count items in a list with the `sum()` function in Python; however, when I search for how to use the `sum()` function on the internet, all I can find is the basic `sum(iterable, start)`, which adds numbers together from each element of the list/array.

Code I found, where each line of the file contains one word, and `file = open("words.txt", "r")`:

```
wordsInFile = sum(1 for line in file)
```

this works in my program, and I kind of see what is happening, but I would like to learn more about this kind of syntax, and what it can or can't recognize besides line.  It seems pretty efficient, but I can't find any website explaining how it works, which prevents me from using this in the future in other contexts.

Comment: The key term you're looking for is [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

First, let's write it a bit differently

```
wordsInFile = sum([1 for line in file])
```

In this form, `[1 for line in file]` is called a list comprehension. It's basically a `for` loop which produces a list, wrapped up into one line. It's similar to

```
wordsInFile = []
for line in file:
  wordsInFile.append(1)
```

but a lot more concise.

Now, when we remove the brackets

```
wordsInFile = sum(1 for line in file)
```

we get what's called a generator expression. It's basically the same as what I wrote before except that it doesn't produce an intermediate list. It produces a special iterator object that supplies the values on-demand, which is more efficient for a function like `sum` that only uses its input once (and hence doesn't need us to waste a bunch of memory producing a big list).